# Missing interval output from icenReg using getSCurves?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have a survival model dataset with both interval and right censored data to test for differences in tagging methods (PIT vs LET). Essentially when an individual loses a tag that is treated as "dead" and when it retains the tag it "survives". I am trying to use the icenReg package to evaluate survival rates (tag retention). I am using this package in particular vs the survival package because I don't capture individuals everyday but rather a few days at a time and then wait a month and attempt to recapture them. Hence, an individual likely will lose a tag but I will only know it lost the tag somewhere between day 30 and day 60 for example (hence interval censored). Additionally, most individuals never lose a tag before the study ended so they are right censored.

I can easily calculate the NPMLE using the interval package and compare two-sample weighted logrank tests or k-sample tests when I have 3 ear tag types to compare.

I want to evaluate a COX PH model because I plan to evaluate how not only survival differs among tag types but also sex and species (this is a smaller and simpler dataset to figure out where I am going wrong and to make it easier for folks). I want to use the parameter estimates to estimate the adjusted survival function. Essentially plot adjusted curves for different groups (should look very similar to Kaplan-Meier curves), but instead show or predict the probability of survival in each group, while keeping the other covariates fixed at their mean values. I am having trouble with plotting these figures in a way that I can do so in ggplot2 because I have missing intervals in the getSCurves output (the getScurves output should extract the estimated survival curve from the ic_sp model: [`https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/icenReg/versions/2.0.15/topics/getSCurves`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/icenReg/versions/2.0.15/topics/getSCurves)).

```
library(icenReg)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

#subset of data set
ID.use<-c(11,12,16,22,25,28,31,35,37,40,44,51,71,77,88,98,100,106,108,111,113,116,117,119,120,122,124,129,149,163,165,182,195,200,207,208,209,219,221,232,236,245,250,262,561,570,583,590,595,617,869,882,905,936,943,972,993,1032,1035,1037,1065,1067,1072,1098,1100,1101,1103,1106,1107,1119,1121,1147,1166,1168,1193,1313,1316,1319,1324,1336,1343,1346,1355,1361,1384,1411,1433,1434,1436,1438,1470,1474,1475,1476,1477,1528,1580,1582,1601,1645,1763,1777,1778,1792,1798,1800,1801,1805,1818,1822,1823,1825,1826,1829,1835,1839,1840,1856,1875,1878,1883,1885,1886,1894,1895,1898,1909,1910,1913,1919,1920,1921,1927,1928,1944,1957,1967,1968,1973,1978,1982,1991,1997,1998,2000,2029,2036,2040,2043,2044,2046,2048,2050,2059,2082,2083,2097,2098,2113,2120,2123,2128,2133,2167,2171,2191,2197,2198,2202,2215,2220,2221,2222,2223,2235,2236,2246,2253,2254,2264,2265,2279,2281,2288,2364,2461,2515,2527,2528,2531,2532,2534,2537,2540,2543,2548,2555,2556,2561,2566,2567,2570,2572,2575,2579,2585,2586,2594,2596,2601,2603,2605,2613,2614,2618,2628,2629,2632,2637,2653,2654,2667,2668,2669,2680,2694,2718,2730,2746,2747,2765,2767,2768,2771,2779,2781,2782,2789,2794,2803,2806,2819,2822,2841,2845,2854,2855,2856,2859,2864,2868,2876,2896,2901,2918,2935,2946,2955,2979,2981,2984,2995,2996,2998,3000,3004,3008,3018,3030,3033,3035,3052,3060,3073,3080,3085,3087,3101,3102,3110,11,12,16,22,25,28,31,35,37,40,44,51,71,77,88,98,100,106,108,113,116,117,119,120,122,124,129,149,163,165,182,195,200,207,208,209,219,221,232,236,245,250,262,561,570,590,595,617,869,882,905,936,943,972,993,1032,1035,1037,1065,1067,1072,1098,1101,1103,1106,1107,1119,1121,1147,1166,1168,1193,1313,1316,1319,1324,1336,1343,1346,1355,1361,1384,1411,1433,1434,1436,1438,1470,1474,1475,1476,1477,1580,1582,1601,1645,1763,1777,1778,1792,1798,1800,1801,1805,1818,1822,1823,1825,1826,1829,1835,1839,1840,1856,1875,1878,1883,1885,1886,1894,1895,1898,1909,1910,1913,1919,1920,1921,1927,1928,1944,1957,1967,1968,1973,1978,1982,1991,1997,1998,2000,2029,2036,2040,2043,2044,2046,2048,2050,2059,2082,2083,2097,2098,2113,2120,2123,2128,2133,2167,2171,2191,2197,2198,2202,2215,2220,2221,2222,2223,2235,2236,2246,2253,2254,2264,2265,2279,2281,2288,2364,2461,2515,2527,2528,2531,2534,2537,2540,2543,2548,2555,2556,2561,2566,2567,2570,2572,2575,2579,2585,2586,2594,2596,2601,2603,2605,2613,2618,2628,2629,2632,2637,2653,2654,2667,2668,2669,2680,2694,2718,2730,2746,2747,2765,2767,2768,2771,2779,2781,2782,2789,2794,2803,2806,2819,2822,2841,2845,2854,2855,2856,2859,2864,2868,2876,2896,2901,2918,2935,2946,2955,2979,2981,2984,2995,2996,2998,3000,3004,3008,3018,3030,3033,3035,3052,3060,3073,3080,3085,3087,3101,3102,3110)
l<-c(32,32,37,32,32,0,35,32,35,32,29,30,87,86,85,32,32,32,32,64,31,32,64,93,92,35,66,64,62,64,30,60,60,57,89,57,28,30,31,31,62,91,34,91,25,37,365,31,27,26,27,31,31,34,28,36,26,429,29,31,94,64,32,33,91,89,30,28,37,0,0,59,59,32,33,32,30,61,32,30,55,56,0,405,31,30,58,87,28,30,29,59,63,64,39,340,309,312,651,0,51,25,24,49,0,51,25,51,25,24,23,49,48,54,29,52,27,49,53,53,26,27,28,52,52,52,27,28,27,30,27,26,0,26,49,23,48,48,327,26,24,24,49,24,24,28,28,50,25,25,0,52,50,47,24,24,26,26,23,22,24,22,21,22,27,26,27,28,26,27,26,24,25,24,382,24,23,25,27,23,23,24,26,26,275,331,31,29,82,30,78,54,28,31,30,80,32,85,31,30,30,78,55,79,30,58,30,62,85,56,30,80,62,81,81,81,62,30,86,31,28,0,83,29,56,26,51,51,13,42,30,18,18,36,37,17,37,29,51,48,28,53,52,52,8,12,10,29,10,27,10,50,10,0,13,19,27,25,28,27,28,27,23,28,24,25,29,23,27,19,24,7,8,23,6,6,26,7,24,25,32,32,37,32,32,0,35,32,35,0,29,85,87,28,85,32,32,32,32,0,32,64,93,92,35,66,64,62,64,30,60,60,57,89,57,28,30,31,31,62,91,34,91,25,37,31,27,26,27,0,31,34,28,0,0,429,0,0,0,64,0,33,89,30,28,0,33,35,59,59,0,33,0,30,61,32,30,55,56,62,405,0,30,58,87,28,30,29,59,0,64,39,309,312,651,315,51,25,0,49,51,51,25,51,25,24,0,49,48,0,29,52,27,28,53,53,26,27,0,52,0,52,27,0,27,0,27,26,28,0,0,0,48,48,0,0,24,24,49,24,24,28,28,50,25,25,26,52,0,47,0,0,26,26,23,22,24,22,0,22,27,26,27,28,26,27,26,24,0,24,382,24,0,25,27,23,23,24,0,0,275,331,31,29,82,55,54,28,31,30,80,0,85,31,30,30,78,55,79,30,0,30,62,0,56,30,0,62,81,81,62,30,86,31,0,82,83,29,0,0,0,51,13,42,30,18,18,29,0,17,37,29,51,48,0,53,0,52,8,12,10,29,10,27,10,50,10,17,13,0,0,25,0,0,28,0,23,0,24,0,0,0,27,19,24,7,8,23,6,6,0,0,24,25)
right<-c(Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,32,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,57,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,59,33,35,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,30,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,288,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,26,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,54,Inf,Inf,28,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,26,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,55,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,29,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,10,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,32,Inf,Inf,Inf,32,Inf,Inf,Inf,60,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,31,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,31,Inf,Inf,Inf,36,26,Inf,29,31,30,Inf,32,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,36,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,32,Inf,32,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,31,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,31,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,24,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,23,Inf,Inf,30,Inf,Inf,Inf,49,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,28,Inf,29,Inf,Inf,28,Inf,29,Inf,Inf,Inf,26,23,23,Inf,Inf,26,26,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,25,Inf,24,24,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,21,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,25,Inf,Inf,Inf,23,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,26,26,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,32,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,30,Inf,Inf,30,Inf,Inf,29,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,28,Inf,Inf,Inf,26,26,23,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,8,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,28,Inf,26,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,12,27,Inf,28,27,Inf,27,Inf,28,Inf,25,29,23,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,26,7,Inf,Inf)
tag<-c("LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","LET","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT")
species<-c("Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","Pman","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT","PIT")

# Create DataFrame
pem <- data.frame(ID.use,l,right,tag,species)

psme.surv.sp.ph =ic_sp(cbind(l,right)~tag, data = pem,bs_samples = 100, model = 'ph')

newdata = data.frame(tag = c('PIT','LET'))
rownames(newdata) = c('PIT','LET')

curveInfo.psme <- getSCurves(psme.surv.sp.ph, newdata)

#estimated survival probability at each Turnbull interval for individuals #with the covariates provided, 1=PIT and 2=LET
ss1.psme <- curveInfo.psme$S_curves[1]
ss2.psme <- curveInfo.psme$S_curves[2]

#Turnbull intervals so 1=start and 2=end
all1.psme <-curveInfo.psme$Tbull_ints[, 1]
all2.psme <-curveInfo.psme$Tbull_ints[,2]

#create a dataframe from the getScurve output that ggplot can read
df.plot <- rbind( data.frame('x' = all1.psme, 'y' =ss1.psme[[1]],
                             'x1'= all1.psme, 'y1' = lag(ss1.psme[[1]],1), #lower change in y
                             'x2'= all2.psme, 'y2' = lag(ss1.psme[[1]],0), #change in x
                             'x3'= all1.psme, 'y3' = lag(ss1.psme[[1]],2), #upper change in y
                             'x4'= all2.psme, 'y4' = lag(ss1.psme[[1]],1), #upper change in x
                             'tag' = rep(names(ss1.psme), length(ss1.psme)),
                             'species' = rep('Pman',length(ss1.psme))),
                  data.frame('x' = all1.psme, 'y' = ss2.psme[[1]],
                             'x1'= all1.psme, 'y1' = lag(ss2.psme[[1]],1),
                             'x2'= all2.psme, 'y2' = lag(ss2.psme[[1]],0),
                             'x3'= all1.psme, 'y3' = lag(ss2.psme[[1]],2),
                             'x4'= all2.psme, 'y4' = lag(ss2.psme[[1]],1),
                             'tag' = rep(names(ss2.psme), length(ss2.psme)),
                             'species' = rep('Pman',length(ss2.psme))))

a1 <- ggplot(df.plot) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x1, yend = y1, colour = tag, linetype = tag)) + #lower vertical change (survival, example: at T=6, S(t) drops from 1 to 0.82))
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x2, yend = y2, colour = tag, linetype = tag))+ #lower horizontal change (time, example: from t=6 to t=7 survival is 0.82)
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x3, yend = y3, colour = tag, linetype = tag)) + #upper vertical change (survival)
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x4, yend = y4, colour = tag, linetype = tag)) #upper horizontal change (time)

a1
```

[image: what it looks like with missing segments and something weird on the right side]

```
#what the plot (a1) should look like (please ignore differences in color and lineshape, that is not what I care about right now):

plot(psme.surv.sp.ph,newdata,lgdLocation="bottomleft" )
```

[image: what is should look like]

So when I go to plot the semi-parametric model, I am missing segments. I can plot the output from the nonparametric model without a problem but I really would like the output for the semi-parametric model that I can then use within ggplot2 for nicer visualization and more control. Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Thank you for your help,
Amanda

Comment: I suspect you meant `data=ch` in several places.You say you are "missing segments" but it is because you are plotting segments with a dataset that you have in no way explained or documented in comments. I'm reasonably conversant in survival analysis but what you are doing is opaque to my efforts at understanding the goals of the code.

Comment: Thank you for catching that error in my code from when I created just a smaller dataset for this posting. I have corrected the error and double checked the code and the results are now producing the exact problem I was originally asking about. I have added figures to also help visually explain my question

Comment: Please read comments completely. I already saw those plots when I corrected that error and ran the code. What I have not seen is any explanation for the various operations in construction of the `df.plot` object. I cannot understand what goals or what the logic is in building its components..